# How do I take a list in one function (num), and square the values in another (square)?

Tags: python-2.7

I have to import a file and have a function read that. Then I have to have another function take that and modify each value by squaring it.. I am new to calling functions within another function. So at the moment it's a mystery to me.

Comment: Be more precise about your question. It seems to me you can easily find the answer by searching for each thing separately. Come back when you've done the reading yourself.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, and you can probably find the answer best by reading some Python examples.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is too broad, I will take a stab at answering it. Let's assume your list is generated in the function `read_file` below. The `return` num_list allows num_list to be available to the caller - the script in this case.

We now have another function `square` which accepts a list of numbers and returns another list containing the squares of the input list.

Here's the file `my_numbers.txt`:

```
$ cat my_numbers.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Here's the code:

```
def read_file():
    num_list = []
    with open('my_numbers.txt', 'r') as fobj:
        for l in fobj:
            num_list.append(int(l.strip()))
    return num_list

def square(num_list):
    square_list = []
    for num in num_list:
        square_list.append(num*num)
    return square_list

num_list = read_file()
square_list = square(num_list)

print 'num_list: ', num_list
print 'square_list: ', square_list
```

### Output:

```
num_list:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
square_list:  [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400]
```

Comment: You answered it completely correct. Thank you, I'll study this and test things out to see how it works. Thanks!